# Reach to the last index starting at index 0

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

The task:

> Given an integer list where each number represents the number of hops
>   you can make, determine whether you can reach to the last index
>   starting at index 0.
>
> For example, `[2, 0, 1, 0]` returns `true` while `[1, 1, 0, 1]` returns
>   `false`.

My solutions:

```
// functional:
const reachLastIndexOf = (arr, start) => {
  if (arr[start] === undefined) return false; 
  const next = start + arr[start];
  if (start === next || next >= arr.length) return false;
  if (next === arr.length -1) return true;
  return reachLastIndexOf(arr, next);
}
console.log(reachLastIndexOf([2, 0, 1, 0], 0)

// imperative:
const reachLastIndexOf2 = arr => {
  let start = 0;
  while(start < arr.length) { // I'm tempted to write `while(true)` here
    if (arr[start] === undefined) return false;
    const next = start + arr[start];
    if (start === next || next >= arr.length) return false;
    if (next === arr.length - 1) return true;
    start = next;
  }
}
console.log(reachLastIndexOf2([1, 1, 0, 1]));
```

Comment: I dare say you misinterpreted the semantics. The problem says `can`, while you take it as `must`. Usually such problems imply that any hop less or equal than `arr[start]` is valid; otherwise it is trivial indeed. Could you share a link to the original problem?

Comment: I don't have a link to the original problem. It's all the information that I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Undelimited blocks as bad

While most C syntax like languages allow for undelimited statement blocks `if (foo) bar;` (proof of just how lazy coders can be) it does contribute to one of the most common and hard to spot syntax derived bugs when later modify code.

You can easily overlook the block delimiters while entering code your mind on the problem, and not the syntax. Later when trying to spot the error it is hard to find as the error looks like a logic error but is in reality a syntax error.

In my view undelimited blocks are a strict no no. If you always add block delimiters then you will save your self many hours of frustration.

```
// Bad 
if (next === arr.length - 1) 
    return true;

// Good
if (next === arr.length - 1) return true;

// Better
if (next === arr.length - 1) {
    return true;
}

// Best
// Note in JS the semicolon is not required for a line terminated with a } and there
// are no edge cases that make this problematic
if (next === arr.length - 1) { return true }
```

### General rule of release.

- Never release any code until at minimum every line has been parsed and run. There is a syntax error `console.log(reachLastIndexOf([2, 0, 1, 0], 0)` is missing a closing `)`
- You should consider code that has not been thoroughly tested as broken. You test code with an aim to find failure.

Your code fails if there is a cyclic loop, eg `reachLastIndexOf([2, 1, -2, 0])`

For the functional style this will throw an error when the call stack overflows, for the imperative style this bug is one of JS ugliest errors as the while loop will run forever and the only way out is via client interaction (navigate off the page, or wait for the timeout dialog to crash the page).

**Note** that the functional style throws an error, however with ES6 the language was to have proper tail calls (means that function calls (depending on the way you call/recurse at the end) will not consume the call stack). 
The implication is that at any time the functional style infinite loop may become blocking like the imperative style so don't use a `try catch` to solve infinite recursion.

### `While (true) {`

In the past setting up in infinite loop in JS had a severe performance penalty as it confused the optimiser.

To prevent the optimiser from attempting to optimise (wasting precious CPU cycles) code with no clear exit from such a loop it was automatically marked as "Do not optimise". The whole function containing the loop and all code within that functions scope was marked.

I am currently unsure if this remains true as Dev Tools no longer displays the `Do Not Optimise` tag on code.

I am of two minds as to deliberate infinite loops however, favouring your approach, even if it's just a dummy exit condition that is never acted on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

When can compare the method signatures of the iterative approach and the functional one, we can see, that for the functional one we have to append the `0` on the first call.

If you want to avoid this - and in this case I think it makes sense - you can add a default parameter into the method signature: `const reachLastIndexOf = (arr, start = 0)`

## Long Condition & [Pattern Matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

The condition `start === next || next >= arr.length` is currently in on if-statement. The `||`-operator operates short-circuit - that means if the first operation is true, the compiler don't validates the second condition. When we split the disjuncture into to two if-statements, we can keep the same short-circuit behavior and create a more [pattern-matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) look and feel:

```
if (start === next) return false 
if (next >= arr.length) return false
```

The advantage is that you have a less logical operator. The less code, the fewer errors and at the same time the readability is increased.
Please note that I have meant this more generally for conditions, even if in this context only a Boolean operator is avoided, the code is still more readable in my view than before.

## Readable Method Names

For this algorithm we need to check if:

- an index exists (`arr[start] === undefined`)
- an index stays on the same place (`start === next`)
- an index is out of the array bound (`next >= arr.length`)
- an index reached the end (`next === arr.length - 1`)

We all now what these checks are meaning but it would be much better if we wrap these into their own functions

```
const reachLastIndexOf = (arr, start = 0) => {
    if (isIndexDefined(arr, start)) return false; 

    const next = start + arr[start];

    if (isStayingInTheSamePosition(start, next)) return false
    if (isOverArrayBound(next, arr)) return false
    if (isReachingTheEnd(next, arr)) return true
    return reachLastIndexOf(arr, next)
}
```

---

```js
const reachLastIndexOf = (arr, start = 0) => {
  if (isIndexDefined(arr, start)) return false;

  const next = start + arr[start];

  if (isStayingInTheSamePosition(start, next)) return false
  if (isOverArrayBound(next, arr)) return false
  if (isReachingTheEnd(next, arr)) return true
  return reachLastIndexOf(arr, next)
}


const isIndexDefined = (array, index) => array[index] === undefined
const isStayingInTheSamePosition = (start, next) => start === next
const isOverArrayBound = (next, array) => next >= array.length
const isReachingTheEnd = (next, array) => next === array.length - 1

console.log(reachLastIndexOf([2, 0, 1, 0], 0));
```

Comment: What's the advantage of having a "pattern matching look and feel" resp. what is the disadvantage if we don't have this "pattern matching look and feel"?

Comment: @thadeuszlay I added a reason to my answer. In short, you have one less condition and less cause for error.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's worth it to have separate function for checking each of the conditions, because I'd have to go that function (which may be on a different file or further away, i.e. I have to scroll to the top or bottom of the current file). But writing it out loud in the current line, it makes it more clear.

Comment: Maybe I haven't fully understand pattern matching, but I don't see much benefit in comparison to a simple `swtich-case` construct.

Answer (score 1):

```
const algo = (arr, idx) => {

   while (idx < arr.length - 1) {
      if (arr[idx] === 0) return false;
      idx += arr[idx];
   }
   return true;
}
```

shorter and cleaner, edge cases skipped

Comment: What is `algo` supposed to accomplish? The name suggests nothing to me.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.